# Prepend a button in each list element of unordered list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, button, listitem, prepend

I am bit new in jQuery and I am trying to prepend a button in each list element of unordered list using jQuery. I thought that the following code would work for me but it did not. Is there anyone who can help a bit?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Button add</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <script >
            var $button = $('<button>').text('Test');
            $('li').prepend($button);
        </script>

        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <ul>
                <li>SubItem</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>SubSubItem</li>
                    <li>SubSubItem</li> 
                </ul>
                <li>SubItem</li>
                <li>SubItem</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: I am trying to insert a button before a text in each list element. Something like that:

```
        <ul>
            <li><button>Test</button>Item</li>
            <ul>
                <li><button>Test</button>SubItem</li>
                <ul>
                    <li><button>Test</button>SubSubItem</li>
                    <li><button>Test</button>SubSubItem</li>
                    ...
        </ul>
```

Comment: Seems to [work ok](http://jsfiddle.net/49b5r6wa/), could you be more specific about what're you trying to get instead? Do you need buttons prepended only for the innermost li elements?

Comment: please make sure your script code appear after the HTML document, or put the code in $(function(){....code here.....})

Comment: @Cattla Thank you very much. It works, when I made it like you said.